# Compiler detects allegro.h, but not allegro_primitives.h

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, allegro

When I compile my Allegro 5 program using g++, it complains about `undefined reference to 'al_init_primitives_addon', al_draw_filled_rectangle` and other such functions that are found in allegro_primitives.h. It does not complain about functions in allegro.h like `al_create_display`.

Includes:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

#include "objects.h"

#include "main.h"
```

Compiler command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o game -lallegro -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib/allegro5
```

Complaints:

```
/tmp/ccAyQlcl.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `al_init_primitives_addon'
/tmp/ccAyQlcl.o: In function `Draw()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38c): undefined reference to `al_draw_filled_rectangle'
main.cpp:(.text+0x415): undefined reference to `al_draw_filled_rectangle'
```

MSVC++ compiles this fine, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with allegro and allegro_primitives. The proper way is:

```
g++ main.cpp -o game $(pkg-config --libs 
   allegro-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0)
```

(All on one line, of course.)

The .pc files will be in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` which needs to be in your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-lallegro` doesn't contain these functions. If you have an old library in system paths and the needed 5.x one in `/usr/lib/allegro5`, you need to pass your `-L` before `-l`.

Comment: g++ main.cpp -o game -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib/allegro5 -lallegro?
This gives me the same errors.